# Create a desktop link by vbscript, ping with arguments, doesn't work

Tags: vbscript

I must create a desktop icon by a vbs script that execute a ping -t , like below, but doesn't work because in the target field of the link, is added double quote character at the beginning and at the end.
That is to say, instead of

```
"C:\WINDOWS\System32\PING.EXE" -t 192.168.000.187
```

is written

```
"C:\WINDOWS\System32\PING.EXE -t 192.168.000.187"
```

How can I solve this problem?

```
Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sLinkFile = "C:\Users\nome cognome\Desktop\Ping POS GENGA01.lnk"
Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile)
oLink.TargetPath = "C:\WINDOWS\System32\PING.EXE -t 192.168.000.187"
oLink.WorkingDirectory = "C:\WINDOWS\system32"
oLink.IconLocation = "E:\BATCH\POSPagoPA\PayPOSEth_Mod1_2.ico, 0"
oLink.Description = "Ping POS GENGA01"
oLink.WindowStyle = "1"
oLink.Hotkey = ""
oLink.Save
```

Comment: Pass  `-t 192.168.000.187` in the `oLink.Arguments` property. See the duplicate target.

Comment: @user692942 oLink.Arguments = "-t 192.168.0.187" works well! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @user692942 for the solution.

```
Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
sLinkFile = "C:\Users\andrea.rossetti\Desktop\Ping POS GENGA01.lnk"
Set oLink = oWS.CreateShortcut(sLinkFile)
oLink.TargetPath = "C:\WINDOWS\System32\PING.EXE"
oLink.Arguments = "-t 192.168.000.187"
oLink.WorkingDirectory = "C:\WINDOWS\system32"
oLink.IconLocation = "E:\BATCH\POSPagoPA\PayPOSEth_Mod1_2.ico, 0"
oLink.Description = "Ping POS GENGA01"
oLink.WindowStyle = "1"
oLink.Hotkey = ""
oLink.Save
```

Comment: Doesn’t need the answer if the duplicate question fixed the problem flag it as such.